# Bash Unix search for a list of words in multiple files

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a list of words I need to check in more one hundred text files.

My list of word's file named : word2search.txt.

This text file contains N word :

```
Word1
Word2
Word3
Word4
Word5
Word6
Wordn
```

So far I've done this bash file :

```sh
#!/bin/bash

listOfWord2Find=/home/mobaxterm/MyDocuments/word2search.txt

while IFS= read -r listOfWord2Find
do
    echo "$listOfWord2Find"
    grep -l -R "$listOfWord2Find" /home/mobaxterm/MyDocuments/txt/*.txt
    echo "================================================================="
done <"$listOfWord2Find"
```

The result does not satisfy me, I can hardly exploit the result

```
Word1
/home/mobaxterm/MyDocuments/txt/new 6.txt
/home/mobaxterm/MyDocuments/txt/file1.txt
/home/mobaxterm/MyDocuments/txt/file2.txt
/home/mobaxterm/MyDocuments/txt/file3.txt
=================================================================
Word2
/home/mobaxterm/MyDocuments/txt/new 6.txt
/home/mobaxterm/MyDocuments/txt/file1.txt
=================================================================
Word3
/home/mobaxterm/MyDocuments/txt/new 6.txt
/home/mobaxterm/MyDocuments/txt/file4.txt
/home/mobaxterm/MyDocuments/txt/file5.txt
/home/mobaxterm/MyDocuments/txt/file1.txt
=================================================================
Word4
/home/mobaxterm/MyDocuments/txt/new 6.txt
/home/mobaxterm/MyDocuments/txt/file1.txt
=================================================================
Word5
/home/mobaxterm/MyDocuments/txt/new 6.txt
=================================================================
```

This is what i want to see :

```
/home/mobaxterm/MyDocuments/txt/file1.txt : Word1, Word2, Word3, Word4
/home/mobaxterm/MyDocuments/txt/file2.txt : Word1
/home/mobaxterm/MyDocuments/txt/file3.txt : Word1
/home/mobaxterm/MyDocuments/txt/file4.txt : Word3
/home/mobaxterm/MyDocuments/txt/file5.txt : Word3
/home/mobaxterm/MyDocuments/txt/new 6.txt : Word1, Word2, Word3, Word4, Word5, Word6
```

I do not understand why my script doesnt show me the Word6(there are files which contains this word6). It stops at word5. To avoid this issue, I've added a new line blablabla (I'm sure to not find this occurence).

If you can help me on this subject :)
Thank you.

Comment: I suggest to postprocess this output from GNU `grep`: `grep -Hf /home/mobaxterm/MyDocuments/word2search.txt /home/mobaxterm/MyDocuments/txt/*.txt`

Comment: You might be interested in grep's -f option.

Comment: @Cyrus : I've tried and it doesnt work as expected. I have nothing displayed on the console when I executed : ```grep -Hf /home/mobaxterm/MyDocuments/word2search.txt /home/mobaxterm/MyDocuments/txt/*.txt```

Comment: re: *stops at word5* ... depending on how `word2search.txt.` was populated and/or edited, I'm wondering if there could be some unwanted non-printing characters in the file? I'd want to review the output from `od -c word2search.txt` and see if there are any characters other than `a-z`, `0-9`, `<space>` and `\n`

Comment: If your files have DOS line endings, fix that first. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another much more elegant approach to search all words on each file. One file at a time.

Use `grep` command multi pattern option `-f, --file=FILE`, and print matched lines with `-o, --only-matching`

Then to pipe massage the resulting words into `csv` list.

Like this:

#### script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

for currFile in $*; do
  matched_words_list=$(grep --only-matching --file=$WORDS_LIST $currFile |sort|uniq|awk -vORS=', ' 1|sed "s/, $//")
  printf "%s : %s\n" "$currFile" "$matched_words_list"
done
```

#### script.sh output

Passing words list file in environment variable: `WORDS_LIST`

Passing inspected files list as arguments list `input.*.txt`

```
export WORDS_LIST=./words.txt; ./script.sh input.*.txt
input.1.txt : word1, word2
input.2.txt : word4
input.3.txt :
```

## Explanation:

#### using words.txt:

```
word2
word1
word5
word4
```

#### using input.1.txt:

```
word1
word2
word3
word3
word1
word3
```

#### And pipe massage the `grep` command

```
grep --file=words.txt -o input.1.txt |sort|uniq|awk -vORS=, 1|sed s/,$//
word1,word2
```

##### output 1

List all matched words from words.txt in inspected file input.1.txt

```
grep --file=words.txt -o input.1.txt
word1
word2
word1
```

##### output 2

List all matched words from words.txt in inspected file input.1.txt

Than sort the output words list

```
grep --file=words.txt -o input.1.txt|sort
word1
word1
word2
```

##### output 3

List all matched words from words.txt in inspected file input.1.txt

Than sort the output words list

Than remove duplicate words

```
grep --file=words.txt -o input.1.txt|sort|uniq
word1
word2
```

##### output 4

List all matched words from words.txt in inspected file input.1.txt

Than sort the output words list

Than remove duplicate words

Than create a `csv` list from the unique words

```
grep --file=words.txt -o input.1.txt|sort|uniq|awk -vORS=, 1
word1,word2,
```

##### output 5

List all matched words from words.txt in inspected file input.1.txt

Than sort the output words list

Than remove duplicate words

Than create a `csv` list from the unique words

Than remove trailing `,` from `csv` list

```
grep --file=words.txt -o input.1.txt|sort|uniq|awk -vORS=, 1|sed s/,$//
word1,word2
```

Comment: Hello Dudi Boy, Thank you for your help and explanation. I have a little bit issue : There is no CSV file created and in my console i have only the name of the file without words found : ```input1.txt : "blank" then input2.txt : "blank"``` any idea ?

Comment: Ok Nevermind, I found where the problem was with my "blank": ```dos2unix words.txt``` :)

Answer (score 0):

The suggest strategy is to scan each line once with all words.

Suggest to write  `gawk` script, which is standard Linux `awk`

#### script.awk

```
FNR == NR { # Only in first file having match words list
  matchWordsArr[++wordsCount] = $0; # read match words into ordered array
  matchedWordInFile[wordsCount] = 0; # reset matchedWordInFile array
}

FNR != NR { # Read line in inspected file
  for (i in matchWordsArr) { # scan line for all match words
    if ($0 ~ matchWordsArr[i]) matchedWordInFile[i]++; # if word is mached increment respective matchedWordInFile[i]
  }
}

ENDFILE{ # on each file read completion
  if (FNR != NR) { # if not first file
    outputLine = sprintf("%s: ", FILENAME); # assign outputLine header to current fileName
    for (i in matchWordsArr) { # iterate over matched words
      if (matchedWordInFile[i] == 0) continue; # skip unmatched words
      outputLine = sprintf("%s%s%s", outputLine, seprator, matchWordsArr[i]); # append matched word to outputLine
      matchedWordInFile[i] = 0; # reset matched words array
      seprator = ","; # set words list seperator ","
    }
    print outputLine;
  } 
  outputLine = seprator = ""; # reset words list seperator "" and outputLine
}
```

#### input.1.txt:

```
word1
word2
word3
```

#### input.2.txt:

```
word3
word4
word5
```

#### input.3.txt:

```
word3
word7
word8
```

#### words.txt

```
word2
word1
word5
word4
```

#### running:

```
$ awk -f script.awk words.txt input.*.txt
input.1.txt: word2,word1
input.2.txt: word5,word4
input.3.txt:
```

Answer (score 0):

Just grep:

```
grep -f list.txt input.*.txt
```

`-f FILENAME` allows to use a file with patterns for grep to search.

If you want to display the filename along with the match, pass `-H` in addition to that:

```
grep -Hf list.txt input.*.txt
```